# BDD with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, testing, bdd

I just started devoloping **ASP.NET MVC Web applicatons**.
One thing I like about ASP.NET MVC is the built in test environment. It gives you the possibility to write unit tests and built test driven web applications (TDD).
But **I'm missing the possibility to do behaviour driven development (BDD)**.

BDD can be done nicely using Ruby On Rails and Cucumber. 
But is there a way to do it the BDD way in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org). It is a BDD framework for .Net and integrates with VisualStudio.
You can combine it with Selenium or WatiN to do BDD with ASP.NET.

The SpecFlow team is currently working on an ASP.NET MVC example using SpecFlow and Selenium, watch the website.

An alternative is using [Cuke4Nuke](http://github.com/richardlawrence/Cuke4Nuke), the direct port of Cucumber for .Net. [Here](http://www.richardlawrence.info/2009/12/03/screencast-testing-web-applications-in-net-with-cuke4nuke-and-watin/) is an example using Cuke4Nuke with WatiN.

Comment: Some more => BehaveN and NBehave (where last one requires custom test runner like Galileo).